# Is using CRUD stored procedures against a view with NOLOCK bad?

Tags: sql-server

(I am crossposting this from SO on the suggestion of a commenter)

Our DBAs have created a pattern where our database layer is exposed to EF via views and CRUD stored procedures. The CRUD works against the view. All the views have the NOLOCK hint. From what I understand, NOLOCK is a dirty read, and that makes me nervous. Our databases are not high volume, but it seems like blanket NOLOCK is not very scalable while maintaining data integrity. I get that the decoupling is a good idea, but the problem there is we don't. Our externally exposed objects look just like our views which map 1 to 1 with our tables.

"If we want to change the underlying data model, we can." ... but we don't. I won't touch on what a PITA this all is from a VS/EF tooling viewpoint.

Is NOLOCK used in this situation bad? Since our database looks exactly like our class library, I think it makes sense to just get rid of the whole view/stored procedure layer and hit the DB direct from EF, does it?

Comment: You can read about the NOLOCK hint [in this question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2684/justify-not-using-nolock-hint-in-every-query). It's not always needed, you should use it only upon need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using NOLOCK blindly is idiotic. There is no best practice at all for this. This could be construed as utter arrogance: that someone knows better than MS who chose READ COMMITTED as the default

From SO: ["Using NOLOCK Hint in EF4?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141104/using-nolock-hint-in-ef4/2141802#2141802). As well as me calling the DBA a muppet, a guy from the MS EF team answers too. And [SQL - when should you use “with (nolock)”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/686724/27535)

In addition, NOLOCK is ignored for updates, inserts, deletes.

Using 1:1 views is idiotic too. It adds no value. From programmers.se ["What popular “best practices” are not always best, and why?"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14856/what-popular-best-practices-are-not-always-best-and-why/14880#14880).

Using a view to hide table changes ad interim is OK, but having the extra layer based on dogma is pointless. And I bet you don't have WITH SCHEMABINDING so the [view can differ from the table anyway (SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321468/select-from-table-vs-select-cola-colb-etc-from-table-interesting-behavio/323103#323103)

Comment: When will people learn that NOLOCK is not the turbo button for database systems?!?

Comment: "But we've *always* done it that way!" -- Makes me want to go all ITG.

Comment: Most of my processes use `NOLOCK` pretty much everywhere, but I think it's OK in our environment - DW with monthly ETL loads, and never any contention since there's no activity during the load process.