# Query takes too much time (2 stages. each stage fast, together - nightmare)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, query

MS-SQL 2008 R2 (Dell, 2 CPU)

This query takes two minutes to run, which is too slow.

```
SELECT * 
FROM t_events WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE order_no = 2783190 
and event_no <= ( SELECT MIN(event_no) 
                  FROM t_events WITH (NOLOCK)
                  WHERE order_no = 2783190 and complaint_id = 80898 
                )
```

However, If I run:

```
SELECT MIN(event_no) FROM t_events WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE order_no = 2783190 and complaint_id = 80898
```

it returns the result, 18880040, in less than a second.

If I run:

```
SELECT * FROM t_events WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE order_no = 2783190 
and event_no <= 18880040
```

it returns about 17 lines in 1 sec.

However, together the query takes 2 minutes to return the same 17 lines.

Why is this happening?

Comment: @Yakov - I noticed your use of NOLOCK. As this link will explain, its benefits come with substantial risks: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/davidlean/2009/04/05/sql-server-nolock-hint-other-poor-ideas/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could insert the rows from the subquery into a temporary table, then JOIN against that table.  Something like:

```
SELECT min_event_no = MIN(event_no) 
INTO #events
FROM t_events WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE order_no = 2783190 
    and complaint_id = 80898; 


SELECT * 
FROM t_events WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN #events e ON t_events.event_no = e.min_event_no
WHERE order_no = 2783190
```

This makes SQL Server perform the two operations independently, which *may* make this query faster.  Potentially you could add appropriate indexes, but without the table definition in your question it's impossible to say.

---

<sup>Be aware of potential issues arising from the use of [WITH (NOLOCK)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10655/is-nolock-always-bad)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Without the plan, I can only help you so much, but the subquery is likely the problem.

If this:

```
SELECT MIN(event_no) FROM t_events WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE order_no = 2783190 and complaint_id = 80898
```

Returns a single record, just store it in a variable like this:

```
DECLARE @min_event_no INT

...

SET @min_event_no = (SELECT MIN(event_no) FROM t_events WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE order_no = 2783190 and complaint_id = 80898)
```

...and use it in the query instead:

```
SELECT * FROM t_events WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE order_no = 2783190 
and event_no <= @min_event_no
```

Hope that helps.

EDIT: Erik caught me doing a bad thing, so let me apply the better practice here, with a temporary stored procedure. For simple, ad-hoc, one-off queries with small result sets (which is what I was assuming this was given the specificity of the WHERE clause), the above will work fine, in my opinion. For anything else, do this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE #GetEvents
 @min_event_no INT
AS
SELECT * FROM t_events WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE order_no = 2783190 
and event_no <= @min_event_no

GO

EXEC #GetEvents @min_event_no = (SELECT MIN(event_no) FROM t_events WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE order_no = 2783190 and complaint_id = 80898);

GO
```

Comment: Be careful with [local variables](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/06/tuning-stored-procedures-local-variables-problems/).